# How to select only one drive when creating system image

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5495-system-image-create-windows-10-a.html) in an attempt to create a system image.

However, I receive an error about not having enough space because I have 3 internal drives: `C:`, `D:` and `H:`. My drives show up similarly to [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt5oW.jpg), but I am unable to exclude the drives I do not need.

How can I only select drive `C:` to be backed up if the other drive selections cannot be deselected?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a script.
Create a new text file, and call it something like SystemBackup.txt (use your imagination).

Make sure you can see the extension ( .txt ), if not, press the
Windows key along with the R key to open the program Run. In the
program Run paste the following :

```
RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Options_RunDLL 7
```

then press Enter. This opens the dialog
window Folder options with the TAB View open. Uncheck "Hide extensions
for known file types"

Paste the code below in the text file, and save it.

```
Set ob = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ob.Run "CMD.EXE /c wbadmin start backup -backuptarget:e: -include:c: -allCritical -quiet"
```

-backuptarget:e: is the disk ( in this case e: ) where the backup will be created. You can change the e in another drive letter like f or g or whatever.
-include:c: that's the source ( in this case C: ) you want to backup. You can change the C in another drive letter like D or H or whatever.

As a last step, you need to change the extension of the text file to vbs.
Windows will ask you if you really want to change the extension, click yes.
Your file should look like this SystemBackup.vbs
If you click this file your backup will start, and your drive C: will be created on E: as a WindowsImageBackup
( If you need to edit the file to backup another drive for example, then right click the file and click edit )

Answer (score -1):

I believe it needs the Reserved to also backup so it can boot properly. Read [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/)

So you need to have both you cannot just select one of the Drives well it is the same drive really its just Partitioned.

Boot Manager and Boot Configuration data are kept in the Reserved Partition.
So if you want to have a backup you will be able to boot from and use. Keep both.

Comment: windows is installed in drive C while I keep documents and some of the programs in drive D and H, I can't just create a system image for windows files?

Comment: Thats what you are doing. The Expanded file system is around 11gb. This consists of C:/ and your System Reserved Partition. Both of these combined are the system image. When it backs this up you will be able to reinstall the complete system how it is. If you have no Documents in C:/ it will not back those up they will be on your drives D and H.

Comment: You don't always have a system reserved partition, if you preformat the drive with one partition formatted ntfs and then install Windows 7, it will not create the reserved partition.